# Invalid and trucated data receiving while calling node API get route

Tags: node.js, json, api, browser, get

While calling Node API get HTTP method data comes in truncated format, incomplete JSON.

But when calling the same api using POSTMAN getting proper response.

If is there any issue regarding NodeAPI please guide how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the code you are using to call the NodeAPI? Please add more info

Comment: Right now not able to share the code, but the API is called by SAGA and the response then sent to the front.